# r - what's the correct cross-platform approach for testing function arguments using testthat

Tags: r, testthat

**Question**

What's the correct way to use `test_that` to test `match.arg()` on different platforms?

**Example**

I'm using `match.arg()` to test the arguments for a function are valid, and testing the function using `testthat::test_that()`.

However, the test will pass or fail differently depending on the Operating System used due to the quote strings.

Consider this example

```
library(testthat)

myFun <- function(args = c('a','b','c')){
  args <- match.arg(args)
  return(args)
}

myFun(args = "x")
```

On a Mac, if the arguments don't match, the error message reads

> 'arg' should be one of “a”, “b”, “c”

Note the `“ ”` quotes.

Whereas on Ubuntu, the error message reads

> 'arg' should be one of "a", "b", "c"

Note the `" "` quotes.

```
## errors on Mac, works on Ubuntu
test_that("quoted string returned",{

  expect_error(myFun(args = c("x")),
               "'arg' should be one of \"a\", \"b\", \"c\"")

})
# Error: Test failed: 'quoted string returned'
# * error$message does not match "'arg' should be one of \"a\", \"b\", \"c\"".
# Actual value: "'arg' should be one of “a”, “b”, “c”"

## works on Mac, fails on Ubuntu
test_that("quoted string returned",{

  expect_error(myFun(args = c("x")),
               "'arg' should be one of “a”, “b”, “c”")

})
```